# How to automate a Telegram bot?

Tags: python-3.x, automation, telegram, telegram-bot, scrape

I recently joined a Telegram bot that requires user interaction every few hours.
Basically I Log into the bot, press a button, check text and then press another button.
Is it possible to automate such a task?

Thank you

Comment: it can be done via Telegram Core API, only if the interactions follow exactly the same procedure.

Comment: You'd better use this site for fixing your issues. You are asking a general question.

Answer (score 1):

Telegram Bot API doesn't allow bots to interact with other bots. So bots won't be useful for such task.
Only way to do that is to use Telegram Core API (the API used in telegram clients), make a custom Telegram client, and do the task through it.